# how to use full text search with assocoative array in mongodb?

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I use mongodb `db.version()` -> 4.4.1 and in my collection I create index for full text search where include gFields column which has tybe `hash` - associative array with key string and value My goal to seacrh by string value in this array too, have a look my index please:

```
    {
    "v" : 2,
    "key" : {
        "_fts" : "text",
        "_ftsx" : 1
    },
    "name" : "TDProductId_text_name_text_categories_text_MerchantCategoryName_text_description_text_price_text_brand_text_sku_text_model_text_declineReasonClass_text_shop_text_identityUniqData_text_gFields_text",
    "sparse" : false,
    "background" : false,
    "weights" : {
        "MerchantCategoryName" : 1,
        "TDProductId" : 1,
        "brand" : 1,
        "categories" : 1,
        "declineReasonClass" : 1,
        "description" : 1,
        "gFields" : 1,
        "identityUniqData" : 1,
        "model" : 1,
        "name" : 1,
        "price" : 1,
        "shop" : 1,
        "sku" : 1
    },
    "default_language" : "english",
    "language_override" : "language",
    "textIndexVersion" : 3
}
```

`gFields` column present, looks like shold works, Becuase mongodb doc seay - "MongoDB provides text indexes to support text search queries on string content. text indexes can include any field whose value is a string or an array of string elements." I have array of srtring elements, but when I try to execute query I faced with empty result

```
db.getCollection('TradeDoublerProduct').aggregate(
[
{ $match: { $text: { $search: "female" } } },

{ $sort: { score: { $meta: "textScore" }  } },

{ $project: { _id: 0, score: { $meta: "textScore" } } },

{ $skip : 0 },
{ $limit : 10 }
],
{ "allowDiskUse" : true }
)
```

result

```
Fetched 0 record(s) in 0ms
```

But I have document in collection which has

```
"gFields" : {
    "(field)g:additional_image_link" : "https://www.desigual.com/dw/image/v2/BCVV_PRD/on/demandware.static/-/Sites-desigual-m-catalog/default/images/B2C/18SWEDX4_5048_3.jpg",
    "(field)g:material" : "COTTON",
    "(field)g:mpn" : "18SWEDX45048L",
    "(field)g:item_group_id" : "18SWEDX4",
    "(field)g:color" : "BLUE",
    "(field)ProductoID" : "18SWEDX45048L",
    "(field)g:size" : "L",
    "(field)g:gender" : "female",
    "(field)g:age_group" : "adult"
},
```

`female` string presetnt in "(field)g:gender" key. What's wrong with that and how to use full text search with assocoative array in mongodb ?

It's works when I use array with key -> balue

```
"gFields" : [ 
    "https://www.desigual.com/dw/image/v2/BCVV_PRD/on/demandware.static/-/Sites-desigual-m-catalog/default/images/B2C/20WGKK03_5000_2.jpg", 
    "ELASTANE, COTTON", 
    "20WGKK035000S", 
    "20WGKK03", 
    "BLUE", 
    "20WGKK035000S", 
    "S", 
    "female", 
    "kids"
],
```

but I want know, it's possible use with associative array ?

Comment: That sample `gFields` value is an object, not an array.

Comment: hm, do available associative array type in mongodb ?

Comment: How would an associative array differ from a BSON object?

Comment: Try build with a wildcard like `db.collection.createIndex( { "$**": "text" } )`.  I don't know if that indexes fields of sub-documents, but it's worth a try.